Counting cells with a specific class in JavaScript
I have a HTML table and the following script to add a specific class to the cells, depending on their content.
Now, I would like to count only the items with class = active and trigger a modal (autoOpen: true) with the number of those items.
Any suggestions?
<script>
$('td').each(function() {
var $this = $(this)
  if ($this.text().match(new RegExp(/^[0-9][A-Z]/)) !== null ) {
    $this.addClass('active');
  }
  if ($this.text().match(new RegExp(/^c[0-9]/)) !== null ) {
    $this.addClass('none');
  }
});
</script>


It seems this answers only a part of my question.

Here is a more efficient code that returns the number of toggled active cells

cache the regular expression so it is only created once
cache the text so it is only read once
use toggleClass to set the class instead of addClass so we can use the result of the match
use filter so we do not have to run twice
Use jQuery UI to show the modal



const re1 = /^[0-9][A-Z]/; 
const re2 = /^c[0-9]/; // 

// Create the dialog once and keep it hidden initially
const $dialog = $('<div></div>').dialog({
  autoOpen: false, // Do not open immediately
  title: 'Active Element Count',
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    Ok: function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  }
});

$("#show").on('click', () => {
  const actives = $('td').filter(function() {
    const text = $(this).text();
    const makeActive = text.match(re1) !== null;
    $(this).toggleClass('active', makeActive);
    $(this).toggleClass('null', text.match(re2) !== null);
    return makeActive;
  }).length;

  // Update the dialog content and open it
  $dialog.html(`Active elements: ${actives}`);
  $dialog.dialog('open');
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1A</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>1B</td>
      <td>Something else</td>
      <td>c2</td>
      <td>Here it is not at the start 1A</td>
      <td>c3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="show">Click for # active</button>




Thanks (also for the suggested improvements). But how can you pass the console.log (const value) to a modal dialog?

See update. I chose jQuery UI

And if you wanted to trigger the modal only when a button is clicked on? (I mean with autoOpen: false)

Just wrap an on click event handler around it

It works in your code snippet. I had to roll back to jquery UI 1.12.0. The dialog appears for a fraction of a second and then disappears. I tried adding e.preventDefault(); but it did not work either.

Why did you have to roll back to 1.12? If you have other scripts that use ui, then make them work with the newest version instead. Make sure to use <button type="button" or add the preventDefault to the form submit event it seems you have in your code

It is probably due to the fact that the page load itself twice (post with action=self).

It likely because you have the button in a form so it submits the page. Make it type="button"
